# Boot manually into Windows 7 when GRUB fails to boot?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, grub, system-repair-disc

I've just edited my hard drive partitions and must've done something wrong, because GRUB enters rescue mode on startup. Can I **boot** into Windows 7 with a system repair disc, or do I have to format the drive and reinstall Windows?

PS: Before anyone gets concerned: Yes, I have everything backed up safely.

Comment: you wrote "I've just edited my hard drive partitions"  <-- oh really. Well, whatever you did, be more specific. So, what change did you make to each hard drive partition that you "edited"?

Answer (score 0):

If you have one drive with many partitions, you have to mark the partition with the windows as "active".

Comment: Recent windowses use multiple partitions, even in the default install. It can be quite annoying for linuxers disliking extended/logical partitions. I don't know, what is the case on GPT.